# Cannot assign twig parameters from middleware in Slim v4

Tags: php, twig, slim

I'm trying to upgrade my website's code from Slim v2 to v4. I'm not a hardcore programmer so I'm facing issues. In Slim v2 I had some middleware where I was able to assign parameters to the Twig view before the route code executed. Now I'm trying to manage the same with Slim v4 but without success.

So this is a test code:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface as RequestHandler;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Slim\Routing\RouteContext;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'config.php';
lib\Cookie::init();

$container = new \DI\Container();

$container->set('view', function($container) {
    return Twig::create(__DIR__ . '/views');
});

$container->set('flash', function ($container) {
    return new \Slim\Flash\Messages();
});

$container->get('view')->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('flash', $container->get('flash'));

AppFactory::setContainer($container);

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, false, false);

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '...',
  'app_secret' => '...',
  'default_graph_version' => '...',
  ]);

$beforeMiddleware = function (Request $request, RequestHandler $handler) use ($fb) {
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    if (!isset($_SESSION['fbuser'])) {
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $permissions = ['email'];
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('...', $permissions);
        $this->get('view')->offsetSet('fbloginurl', $loginUrl);       
    }
    else {
        $this->get('view')->offsetSet('fbuser', $_SESSION['fbuser']);
    }
    $uri = $request->getUri();

    $this->get('view')->offsetSet('currenturl', $uri);

    return $response;
};


$app->add($beforeMiddleware);

$app->get('/test', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $oViewParams = new \lib\ViewParams("home", "", "", "", "");
    $oProfession = new \models\Profession();
    $oBlogPost = new models\BlogPost();
    $oBlogTopic = new models\BlogTopic();
    $professions = $oProfession->getProfessionsWithLimit(14);
    $posts = $oBlogPost->getMainPagePosts();

    echo $this->get('view')->offsetGet('fbloginurl'); 
    $params = array('professions' => $professions,
        'posts' => $posts,
        'viewp' => $oViewParams->getMassParams());
    return $this->get('view')->render($response, 'index.html', $params);
});

$app->run();
```

When I use `echo $this->get('view')->offsetGet('fbloginurl');` within the middleware it shows up. When I use the same within the route there is nothing show up...

Comment: Isn't this (`$handler->handle($request);` where it calls the next level of the code, which is before you set anything.  Try moving that line to the end of the `$beforeMiddleware` to see if it changes.

Comment: Thank you! That was it!

Answer (score 1):

The next code in the chain of middleware (or your routes) is called when you have...

```
$response = $handler->handle($request);
```

As this is before you set any of the values you want to use in twig, they aren't yet set.  Move the above line after setting these value and the values should then be available to the rest of the code.

Comment: @TamásVarga As the answer [seems to solve your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748055/cannot-assign-twig-parameters-from-middleware-in-slim-v4/66748637#comment117991278_66748055), please, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted for future readers.